# Replace part of substring with specific characters based on delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

```
String s = "abc//jason:1234567@123.123.213.212/";
```

I want to replace all the substring before and after ":" delimiter with "......."

I want my final output to be :

```
"abc//.....:.......@123.123.213:212/"
```

I tried doing this since there is a second : in the string it gets messed up, is it there better way to be able to get my output:

```
  String [] headersplit;
            headersplit = s.split(":");
```

Comment: Is format of input string fixed? From your example it could be described as `[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\/`. In that case you could use regular expresison of write simple function which using standart String API without regex.

Comment: ya exactly in that format, r u implying a use of regex?

Comment: No, I don't think that regex is needed here, it is easier to find first occurence of "//" because it fixed, than find occurence of ":" after that.

Comment: i essentially just want the characters from // to : to be replaced , the characters from  : to @ to be replaced

Comment: Yep, I understood. Look at the answer.

Comment: How exactly would u use standart String API without regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate only symbols between "//" and "@" then algorithm is simple, provided that mention symbols are compulsory.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc//jason:1234567@123.123.213.212/";

        System.out.println(replaceSensitiveInfo(s));
    }

    static String replaceSensitiveInfo(String src) {
        int slashes = src.indexOf("//");
        int colon = src.indexOf(":", slashes);
        int at = src.indexOf("@", colon);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(src);

        sb.replace(slashes + 2, colon, ".".repeat(colon - slashes - 2));
        sb.replace(colon + 1, at, ".".repeat(at - colon - 1));

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: wym by .repeat()

Comment: repeat is the method of java.lang.String (starting from java 11) which creates a new String with repeated argument, in this case repeated periods e.g. ".......". See more https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)

Comment: if ur using java8 is there any easier way

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but it works for your example and should work for others:

```
String s = "abc//jason:1234567@123.123.213:212/";

String result = replaceSensitiveInfo(s);

private String replaceSensitiveInfo(String info){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(info);

    String substitute = ".";

    int start = sb.indexOf("//") + 2;
    int end = sb.indexOf(":");

    String firstReplace = substitute.repeat(end - start);

    sb.replace(start, end, firstReplace);

    int start2 = sb.indexOf(":") + 1;
    int end2 = sb.indexOf("@");

    String secondReplace = substitute.repeat(end2 - start2);
    sb.replace(start2, end2, secondReplace);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: if ur using java8 is there any easier way instead of .repeat